# Android ble scan extended advertising in background

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I’m using android 9.0 application to advertising and scanning. When I use low latency scan mode scanning in foreground, I can get the scan result. But when I turn off the screen or let the application in background, I can not get scan result of extended advertising!
Is that any detail I had not found? Or, how can I get the extended advertising during the scanner is in background?
Thanks!

Comment: This question might be more for the Android Stack Exchange at https://android.stackexchange.com/ so maybe post your question there as well if you haven't already.

Comment: For scanning in background you should add the scan filters, otherwise you will not get any scan results!